# MCMC - How to derive the acceptance ratio from Markov chain detailed balance?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, mcmc-acceptance-rate

Please explain how the acceptance ratio:

$$\rm A(x\to y) =\min\left(1,\frac{P(y)q(y\to x) }{P(x) q(x\to y) }\right)$$

is derived from the detailed balance:

$$\rm \frac{A(x\to y) }{A(y\to x)}=\frac{P(y)q(y\to x) }{P(x) q(x\to y) }  .$$

Reading the articles but not sure how the ratio is logically derived from the detailed balance.

- [Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC)](https://people.duke.edu/%7Eccc14/sta-663/MCMC.html#metropolis-hastings-sampler)

[image]

- [Wikipedia Metropolis–Hastings algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm#Formal_derivation)
  [image]
- [MCMC - Metropolis Hasting: formal derivation of detailed balance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271385/mcmc-metropolis-hasting-formal-derivation-of-detailed-balance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathop{P}\left(x\right)\mathop{q}\left(x\rightarrow y\right) > \mathop{P}\left(y\right)\mathop{q}\left(y\rightarrow x\right)$, then the process moves from $x$ to $y$ too often.
Setting $\mathop{A}\left(x\rightarrow y\right)=\dfrac{\mathop{P}\left(y\right)\mathop{q}\left(y\rightarrow x\right)}{\mathop{P}\left(x\right)\mathop{q}\left(x\rightarrow y\right)}$ and $\mathop{A}\left(y\rightarrow x\right)=1$ achieves detailed balance by reducing the probability that a move from $x$ to $y$ is made such that $\mathop{P}\left(x\right)\mathop{q}\left(x\rightarrow y\right)\mathop{A}\left(x\rightarrow y\right)=\mathop{P}\left(y\right)\mathop{q}\left(y\rightarrow x\right)$ holds.

Analogously, if $\mathop{P}\left(x\right)\mathop{q}\left(x\rightarrow y\right) \leq \mathop{P}\left(y\right)\mathop{q}\left(y\rightarrow x\right)$, take $\mathop{A}\left(y\rightarrow x\right)=\dfrac{\mathop{P}\left(x\right)\mathop{q}\left(x\rightarrow y\right)}{\mathop{P}\left(y\right)\mathop{q}\left(y\rightarrow x\right)}$ and $\mathop{A}\left(x\rightarrow y\right)=1$.

Written more compactly, we thus have $\mathop{A}\left(x\rightarrow y\right)=\min\left(1, \dfrac{\mathop{P}\left(y\right)\mathop{q}\left(y\rightarrow x\right)}{\mathop{P}\left(x\right)\mathop{q}\left(x\rightarrow y\right)}\right)$.

Answer (score 3):

The acceptance probability $A(x\to y)$ is **not** derived from detailed balance. It is the opposite: given this choice of acceptance probability the Markov kernel satisfies detailed balance
$$
p(x)\int q(x\to y)A(x\to y)\,\text dy=\int p(y) q(y\to x) A(y\to x)\,\text dy
$$
But so do (infinitely) other choices of transition kernels.

For instance, [Tjelmeland](http://cds.cern.ch/record/848061/files/cer-002531395.pdf) defines a multiple choice proposal with acceptance probability
$$A_\ell(x\to y_\ell)=p_\ell(y_\ell)\Big/ p(x)+\sum_{j=1}^m p_j(y_j)$$
that generalises [Barker’s (1965)](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/tag/barkers-algorithm/) acceptance probability,
$$A(x\to y)=p(y)\Big/ p(x)+p(y)$$

[Delayed acceptance](http://xianblog.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/delayed-acceptance-with-prefetching/) is another version of a valid transition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There could be many acceptance methods but Metropolis happened to use $min( 1, \frac {P(y)}{P(x)} )$ by setting A(y->x) to 1 because it is OK to do so?